# How to add list type properties to vertices in the NebulaGraph database?

Tags: nebula-graph

We are testing NebulaGraph database on AWS and need to add dynamic vertex properties. For example, a Person vertex may have purchased a product many times, how to add a list time `orderTime` property, and every time the person purchases the product, a timestamp or time string is pushed into this list type property?

Finally we get `(v:Person{orderTime:[1672898563,1672897563,1672896563]})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, if the purchase event is an edge/relationship between two vertices, and it’s multi-to-multi, it’s a tyical case we should use the rank of the edge as the timestamp. In NebulaGraph, there is no “id” or Key for an edge, instead, a 4-tuple defined one instance of edge, refer to [here](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/1.introduction/2.data-model/) for details.

While, if in the case the purchase should be considerred as a “property” for a vertex under TAG: Person, we could leverage the self-loop edge to enable the list of `orderTime` property, see more from [here](https://docs.nebula-graph.io/3.3.0/8.service-tuning/2.graph-modeling/#set_temporary_properties_through_self-loop_edges) for details.

Besically, the two approaches share similar ideas under the hood, just for second one, the source and target vertices are the same.

Comment: Thank you, Wey! I read the docs about self-looping edges and tested it and it looks like the workaround we need. A bit complex though.

Comment: Welcome @randomv ❤, true, as NebulaGraph doesn’t support list datatype, this is a mitigation with the cost of complexity :(